# Javascript parent child Tree Merging

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, underscore.js, parent-child

Below are the three arrays, I want to merge them using a mergelist function.
I am new to javascript, Please help me with this.

```
var list1 = [
    {name: 'Parent'},
    {name: 'child1', parent: ‘parent’},
    {name: 'child2', parent: ‘parent’},
    {name: 'child21', parent: 'child2'}
];

var list2 = [
    {name: 'child1'},
    {name: 'child11', parent: 'child1'},
    {name: 'child12', parent: 'child1'}
];

var list3 = [
    {name: 'child2'},
    {name: 'child22', parent: 'child2'},
    {name: 'child23', parent: 'child2'}
];
```

Implement a function that merges of all of the trees in the array into one combined tree.

Please help me with the code. Thank you
I have tried with this code but I only was able to do it for 2 trees and not exactly what I want.

```
var list1 = [
    {
        Parent: 'parent',
        children: [
            {
                parent: 'child1',
                children: []
            },
            {
                parent: 'child2',
                children: [
                  {
                    parent:'child21',
                    children :[]
                  }]
            }]
    }
];

var list2 = [
    {
        parent: 'child1',
        children: [
            {
                parent: 'child11',
                children: []
            },
            {
                parent: 'child12',
                children: []
            }]
    }
];

var list3 = [
  {
        parent: 'child2',
        children: [
            {
                parent: 'child22',
                children: []
            },
            {
                parent: 'child23',
                children: []
            }]
    }
]
var addNode = function(nodeId, array) {
  array.push({parent: nodeId, children: []});
};

var placeNodeInTree = function(nodeId, parent, treeList) {
  return treeList.some(function(currentNode){

    // If currentNode has the same id as the node we want to insert, good! Required for root nodes.
    if(currentNode.parent === nodeId) {
      return true;  
    }

    // Is currentNode the parent of the node we want to insert?
    if(currentNode.parent === parent) {

      // If the element does not exist as child of currentNode, create it
      if(!currentNode.children.some(function(currentChild) {
        return currentChild.parent === nodeId;
      })) addNode(nodeId, currentNode.children);

      return true;
    } else {

      // Continue looking further down the tree
      return placeNodeInTree(nodeId, parent, currentNode.children);
    }
  });
};

var mergeInto = function(tree, mergeTarget, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || undefined;
  tree.forEach(function(node) {

    // If parent has not been found, placeNodeInTree() returns false --> insert as root element
    if(!placeNodeInTree(node.parent, parentId, mergeTarget)){
      list1.push({parent: node.parent, children:[]});
    }

    mergeInto(node.children, mergeTarget, node.parent);

  });
};

mergeInto(list2, list1);

document.write('<pre>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(list1, null, 4));
console.log(list1);
document.write('</pre>');
```

Comment: You need to at least make an attempt yourself. If you get stuck, then ask a specific question about your code. Also, you would need to explain what the result of the merge should look like.

Comment: I attempted it by my self, I first tried to use lodash and underscore's different functions, Such as _.merge, _.defaultsdeep, _.assign. but I am not getting the result. I am really new to javascript. Tried every possible solution I could and I posted it here

Merged array:

var list1 = [
    {name: 'Parent'},
    {name: 'child1', parent: ‘parent’},
    {name : 'child 11', Parent : 'child1'},
    {name:'child12', parent :'child1'),
    {name: 'child2', parent: ‘parent’},
    {name: 'child21', parent: 'child2'}.
    {name: 'child22', parent: 'child2'},
    {name: 'child23', parent: 'child2'}
];

Comment: What do you like to achieve? a tree or a list?

Comment: var list1 = [ {name: 'Parent'}, {name: 'child1', parent: ‘parent’}, {name : 'child 11', Parent : 'child1'}, {name:'child12', parent :'child1'), {name: 'child2', parent: ‘parent’}, {name: 'child21', parent: 'child2'}. {name: 'child22', parent: 'child2'}, {name: 'child23', parent: 'child2'} ];

This should be the output, it should be the merged tree of the above 3 array of trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an easy problem, but the data source is misleading with duplicate items sometimes with parent property and sometimes without.

The first part is to clean the data and build a flat array with single name and if possible with parent. The data is stored in `data`. The first output is this result.

The second part is to build a tree with the data. For every object, a node for `name` is build and for every given `parent` a node is created, if it is not already there.

```js
var list1 = [{ name: 'parent' }, { name: 'child1', parent: 'parent' }, { name: 'child2', parent: 'parent' }, { name: 'child21', parent: 'child2' }],
    list2 = [{ name: 'child1' }, { name: 'child11', parent: 'child1' }, { name: 'child12', parent: 'child1' }],
    list3 = [{ name: 'child2' }, { name: 'child22', parent: 'child2' }, { name: 'child23', parent: 'child2' }],
    data = function (data) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!o[a.name]) {
                r.push(a);
                o[a.name] = a;
                return;
            } 
            if (!(parent in o[a.name])) {
                o[a.name] = a;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }([].concat(list1, list2, list3)),
    tree = function (data) {
        var r, o = {};
        document.write('<pre>data: ' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
        data.forEach(function (a, i) {
            a.children = o[a.name] && o[a.name].children;
            o[a.name] = a;
            if (a.parent === undefined) {
                r = a;
                return;
            }
            o[a.parent] = o[a.parent] || {};
            o[a.parent].children = o[a.parent].children || [];
            o[a.parent].children.push(a);
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>tree: ' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have also written a code which worked but the logic was different. I will compare mine with yours. Thank you again for the help.